# Overcome the error: Initialization failed in rstan::sampling()

Tags: r, stan, rstan

`rstan::sampling()`   fails with the following error.

```
[1] "Error in sampler$call_sampler(args_list[[i]]) : Initialization failed."
[1] "error occurred during calling the sampler; sampling not done"
Stan model 'foo' does not contain samples.
Stan model 'foo' does not contain samples.
Stan model 'foo' does not contain samples.
Stan model 'foo' does not contain samples.
```

where, `foo` means a name of a stan file `foo.stan`.

Comment: Please elaborate your question with example data and required output

Comment: we could really use a [mcve] here ...

Comment: Thank  your for reply, @SaiPrabhanjanReddy, I try to make a reproducible example of the above, please, wait. To tell the truth, this is several weeks ago error and I forget how to replicate it.

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker, This occurs in my package on CRAN, so, I try to make a code to make the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproducible example that is inconsistent and thus impossible to initialize:

```
model <- 
  stan_model(model_code = "parameters { real<lower = 0> y; }
                           transformed parameters { real<upper = -1> z = y; }")

fit <- sampling(model)
```

This produces the following output in RStan 2.18.1:

```
> fit <- sampling(model)

SAMPLING FOR MODEL '64719d6dccb64c32b0d897ef1f340d74' NOW (CHAIN 1).
Chain 1: Initialization between (-2, 2) failed after 100 attempts. 
[1] "Error in sampler$call_sampler(args_list[[i]]) : Initialization failed."
error occurred during calling the sampler; sampling not done
```

Here's the beginning of the resulting `fit` structure:

```
> str(fit)
Formal class 'stanfit' [package "rstan"] with 10 slots
  ..@ model_name: chr "64719d6dccb64c32b0d897ef1f340d74"
  ..@ model_pars: chr [1:3] "y" "z" "lp__"
  ..@ par_dims  :List of 3
  .. ..$ y   : num(0) 
  .. ..$ z   : num(0) 
  .. ..$ lp__: num(0) 
  ..@ mode      : int 2
  ..@ sim       : list()
```

So you can use the test

```
length(fit@sim) == 0
```

If there are samples, they'll show up as a list in variable `sim`.

**WARNING**:  This problem often arises because constraints are not well formulated on parameters.  Stan assumes every value of the parameters that satisfies the constraints has support in the model.  If it doesn't, the model will typically fail to initialize.  The best solution is to fix the constraints on the parameters and the scales of the parameters so that the model can be initialized randomly. If the constraints are well formulated, numerical issues can also cause problems.  Scaling parameters to unit scale can help.  Also, big interval uniform priors can be a problem because initialization will be around the halfway point.  If the problem is well scaled and constraints are well formed, then you can reduce the interval for initialization, which can help.  Otherwise, you really have to supply your own sensible inits for things to be robust.  Retrying if 100 tries already failed is not usually going to work.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the `.stan` file so that  the upper and lower ranges in parameter block is compatible between `parametere block` and `transformed paramter block`, then I could remove the above error itself and no longer need to an R object representing the error. Thank you very much. It is good for me to post this question since I can get your fruitful answer. Thank you.